# Do I need to use square oAuth to add a fee to users transactions done via square in my app?

Tags: payment, square, square-connect

I have been reading square [documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth/#whyoauth) in and out but am still confused if I square offers a service that would allow me as a developer to integrate it in my app to enable my users to connect their accounts and use it all this while I'm receiving a fee (or a cut) on each transaction. 
I know [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) does have that via their connect API pretty simply addressed. Square documentation thought, isn't clear to me, if they have it , do I need to implement the oAuth API? other APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square's APIs support OAuth, which allows you to create applications for other people to connect their accounts to. As of today, you are not able to charge a cut of each transaction, but that is a feature that Square is currently working on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, good information, I would appreciate and accept it as the answer if you could provide a ref. Thanks! 
It's surprising if they haven't enabled that yet!

Comment: Here is the link to OAuth, but you won't find anything on Multi-Party Settlement (since it isn't offered yet). https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth/#oauth-overview

Comment: Sounds good, how do you know they're working on it though? is it pure speculation?

Comment: No, I work on the Square developer platform, and it is a highly requested feature ;)

Comment: Oh nice! Then yes, please add a huge request on my behalf too! :) Cheers

Comment: Is there any thead that I could subscribe to and get notification on the progress of this by Square? Thanks

Comment: Any update on this? Has Square team added the feature ?

Comment: Thanks for response, any estimate of time? Square seems to have marketplace API which is what I thought does what this question seeks but in Square websites it says that it's only available in US. Is what you have in mind different than marketplace API?

Comment: Yes, and we don't have a public timeline, sorry.